# Opening password protected .xls file

Tags: epplus

Can I use EPplus to open password protected .xls files?

My current method only works for .xlsx files

```
    Dim oFileInfo As New FileInfo("C:\Temp\test.xlsx")
    Dim oPackage As New ExcelPackage(oFileInfo, "test")

    For Each oSheet As ExcelWorksheet In oPackage.Workbook.Worksheets
        If oSheet.Name = "Alles" Then
            Debug.Print(oSheet.Cells("A1").Value)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

EPPlus is **only** able to open `.xlsx` files; it cannot open `.xls` files.

To open `.xls` files you should automate Excel.

**Note:** You should not automate Excel from a service (or any non-interactive user); as Excel can appear to spontaneously lock up if a dialog box appears and there's no user to click it.

Microsoft *specifically* warns against trying to automate Office application from non-interactive session (e.g. services, web-servers, scheduled tasks).

> ## [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)
>
> All current versions of Microsoft Office were designed, tested, and configured to run as end-user products on a client workstation. They assume an interactive desktop and user profile. They do not provide the level of reentrancy or security that is necessary to meet the needs of server-side components that are designed to run unattended.
>
> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

The NPOI.dll library can interact .xls as well as .xlsx files, and you'd program with it similarly to EPPlus. (worked at a significant company that used it in a web app to pull data out of uploaded .xls as well as .xlsx files)

I don't know how up-to-date it is with .Net Core, etc.

It is a port to .Net of the Java POI library.